# Meaning of a toast with teeth

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

Two girls making a toast.

First said: “We, my friend, are having a true girls’ night.To finally having a girl around, I don’t want to smash in the teeth with a shovel.”

Second girl: "To us!"

Can someone help me with the meaning of the phrase about teeth?

Ok! Source: Book I'm reading. Demons from J.L. Drake

Comment: Could you [edit] your post to include the source?

Comment: The meaning appears to be 'having a girl around _whom_ I don't want to smash in the teeth...' She apparently finds most other girls extremely annoying to the point of (metaphorically) wanting to be violent towards them.